# How do I change the color of User Types in VB.NET code?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, syntax-highlighting

In a VB.NET Web Site, the User Types syntax coloring doesn't work. What are potential causes of this? It seems to not understand the difference between a "User Type" and an "Identifier."

Note: C# works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax coloring is slightly different for VB.NET compared to what you find in C#. As you've said, changing the color for "User Types" does what you expect given code written in C#. **To change the color of the user types in VB.NET code, you need to change the color of "VB User Types":**

[image: Setting color of "VB User Types" in Options dialog]